# fullcalendar pass in array to set events

Tags: ajax, fullcalendar

I would like to pass in an array of IDs that will be used to select the events I want to display.  The fullcalendar displays all of the events if I do not use the 'data' attribute with the ID array.  When the data attribute is added I get the error message 'There was an error fetching events!'

This is the document ready function:

```
var groupSelectedArray = [];

groupSelectedArray[0] = '1';
groupSelectedArray[1] = '2';

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    header:
    {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    titleFormat: {month: 'MMMM'},              
    defaultView: 'month',                 
    editable: false,
    events: function (start, end, groupSelectedArray, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetAllEvents", "Home")',
            data: { selectedGroups: groupSelectedArray },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (doc) {
                var events = [];                     
                $(doc).each(function () { 
                    events.push({
                        title: $(this).attr('title'),  
                        start: $(this).attr('start'), 
                        end: $(this).attr('end'),
                        id: $(this).attr('id'),
                        description: $(this).attr('description'),
                        color: $(this).attr('color'), 
                        textColor: 'black'
                    });

                });
                callback(events);
                } ,                                                                   
            error: function () {
                alert("There was an error fetching events!")
            }
        });
    }
```

This is the C# method:

```
 public JsonResult GetAllEvents(string[] selectedGroups)
    {

        var eventList = GetEventsFromDatabase(selectedGroups);
        var rows = eventList.ToArray();

        return Json(rows, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What I did to get this to work was change the 'data' part of the ajax call:
Replace this:

```
{ selectedGroups: groupSelectedArray },
```

to this:

```
 data: JSON.stringify(groupData),
```